# Packages cancel and schulschriften_lin not working together?

Tags: cancel

When I use the "schulschriften_lin"-package, cancellation is no longer working (see MWE).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cancel}

\usepackage{schulschriften_lin} % Lineaturen fuer Schulschriften

\begin{document}
    \[ y = \frac{5\cdot 27}{9 \cdot 5} \]

    \[ y = \frac{\cancel{5} \cdot 27}{9 \cdot \cancel{5} } \]
\end{document}
```

Any suggestion to reactivate cancel?

Comment: The problem is related to the fact that the `eepic` package gets loaded which redefines low-level commands related to `\line`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Load `cancel` later:

For running `xelatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{schulschriften_lin} % Lineaturen fuer Schulschriften
\usepackage{cancel}
\begin{document}
    \[ y = \frac{5\cdot 27}{9 \cdot 5} \]

    \[ y = \frac{\cancel{5} \cdot 27}{9 \cdot \cancel{5} } \]
\end{document}
```

for running `pdflatex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pict2e}
\usepackage{schulschriften_lin} % Lineaturen fuer Schulschriften
\usepackage{cancel}
\begin{document}
    \[ y = \frac{5\cdot 27}{9 \cdot 5} \]

    \[ y = \frac{\cancel{5} \cdot 27}{9 \cdot \cancel{5} } \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This "fix" does not work for my installation (and I am not the OP).

Comment: see edited answer. I suppose you run `pdflatex`

Comment: Package pict2e did the magic! Thanks a lot!